# Array returning images from previous iteration

Tags: php, arrays

For some reach my array returns the data numerous times, for different arrays after filtering via a `foreach` in the second example the post only contains 1 unique link so the rest shouldn't exist at all, it should print simply the data from `image_1` here's the PHP code.

```
$imagecounter = 1;
foreach ($html2->find('.post img') as $source) {    
    $link = $source->src;
    if (strpos($link, 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/') !== false) { 
        $data['image_'.$imagecounter++.''] = $link;
    } 
}
```

And here's the array.

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://www.example.com/something-with-data/
    [featured_image] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-1.jpg
    [name] => Main Categories
    [image_1] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-11.jpg
    [image_2] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-1.jpg
    [image_3] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-1.png
    [image_4] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-2.jpg
    [image_5] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-3.jpg
    [image_6] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-4.jpg
    [image_7] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-5.jpg
    [image_8] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-6.jpg
    [image_9] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-7.jpg
    [image_10] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-8.jpg
    [image_11] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/something-9.jpg
)

Array
(
    [url] => https://www.example.com/a-completely-different-post
    [featured_image] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/UmekRLrlwK8.jpg
    [name] => Main Categories
    [image_1] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/UmekRLrlwK8.jpg (THIS IS FROM THE NEW ITERATION)
    [image_2] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-1.jpg
    [image_3] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-1.png
    [image_4] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-2.jpg
    [image_5] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-3.jpg
    [image_6] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-4.jpg
    [image_7] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-5.jpg
    [image_8] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-6.jpg
    [image_9] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-7.jpg
    [image_10] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-8.jpg
    [image_11] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-9.jpg
    [image_12] => https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/something-10.jpg
)
```

Comment: Just so you know, you dont need to append an empty string to the end your incremented keys.  (`.''`)   We see coders do this too often and there is no point.

Comment: You need to reset `$data` on each iteration (not the code shown)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with an empty `$data` array.

```
$data = [];
$imagecounter = 1;
foreach ($html2->find('.post img') as $source) {    
    $link = $source->src;
    if (strpos($link, 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/') !== false) { 
        $data['image_'.$imagecounter++.''] = $link;
    } 
}
```

If you need to store multiple sets of `$data`, then you can store each new `$data` batch in a parent array.

```
foreach ($htmls as $html2) {
    $data = [];
    $imagecounter = 1;
    foreach ($html2->find('.post img') as $source) {    
        $link = $source->src;
        if (strpos($link, 'https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/') !== false) { 
            $data['image_'.$imagecounter++.''] = $link;
        } 
    }
    $result[] = $data;
}
```